# How to change auth page in active_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, authorization, activeadmin

I need change this active_admin auth page:

[image]

to this:

[image]

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just generated the views with `rails g devise:views`, I then copied
 the files generated into the folder `app/views/active_admin/devise`

Comment: Thank you for answering your question--this is helpful to people who find your question later.  You can give your answer the checkmark, too.